# Ansible Hetzner Cloud - Create a server in private network

Tags: networking, deployment, ansible, hcloud

I am using Ansible to create a server in the Hetzner Cloud, the playbook reads:

```yaml
- name: create the server at Hetzner
  hetzner.hcloud.hcloud_server:
    name: "{{server_hostname}}"
    enable_ipv4: false
    enable_ipv6: false
    server_type: cx11
    location: "{{server_location}}"
    image: ubuntu-22.04
    ssh_keys:
    - "mykey"
    state: present
    api_token: "{{hetzner_secret}}"
    private_networks: ipfire
  register: server
```

My aim is to integrate the new server into the private network named 'ipfire' that I have previously created. The server should not be accessible via the internet, so I have disabled ipv4 and ipv6. Rather, I'd like to access the server by connecting via OpenVPN to the private network 'ipfire' and connect by use of ssh from there.

Unfortunately, I get an error message as follows:

```yaml
PLAY [Order servers] ********************************************************************************************************

TASK [hetznerserver : create the server at Hetzner] *************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (hetzner.hcloud.hcloud_server) module: private_networks. Supported parameters include: rebuild_protection, api_token, location, enable_ipv6, upgrade_disk, ipv4, endpoint, ipv6, firewalls, server_type, state, force, labels, ssh_keys, delete_protection, image, id, name, enable_ipv4, placement_group, force_upgrade, user_data, datacenter, rescue_mode, allow_deprecated_image, volumes, backups."}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

The module `private_networks` does not seem to work like this?

Comment: Error messages like `Unsupported parameters for (<moduleName>) module: <givenParameter>. Supported parameters include: <supportedParametersList>` are just syntax errors of the module used. You may need to look up the documentation [`hcloud_server module` – Create and manage cloud servers on the Hetzner Cloud](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/hetzner/hcloud/hcloud_server_module.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error messages like `Unsupported parameters for (<moduleName>) module: <givenParameter>. Supported parameters include: <supportedParametersList>` are usually syntax errors of the module used.

Therefore one may need to look up the respective documentation, in the example case [`hcloud_server module` – Create and manage cloud servers on the Hetzner Cloud](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/hetzner/hcloud/hcloud_server_module.html).

If the documentation shows the [Parameters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/hetzner/hcloud/hcloud_server_module.html#parameter-private_networks) in question are available, it indicates

- either a version mismatch of module used, means the used version is too old and an update is necessary
- or an bug within the module code and further debugging and investigation within the module code is necessary

**Code and Documentation Links**

- [Community Authors> hetzner> hcloud](https://galaxy.ansible.com/hetzner/hcloud?extIdCarryOver=true&sc_cid=701f2000001OH7YAAW)
- [`ansible-collections / hetzner.hcloud`](https://github.com/ansible-collections/hetzner.hcloud)

After further investigation it might turn out that the parameter in question was introduced recently, in example

- Github `hetzner.hcloud` Issue #[150](https://github.com/ansible-collections/hetzner.hcloud/issues/150) "*Unable to create cloud server without public ipv4 and ipv6*"
- Github `hetzner.hcloud` Pull #[160](https://github.com/ansible-collections/hetzner.hcloud/pull/160) "*Add possibility to specify private network when creating or updating servers*"

which indicates in your example case that you'll need to update the Ansible Collection module in question since the parameter wasn't introduced in your used version of the module but [as of v1.9.0](https://github.com/ansible-collections/hetzner.hcloud/releases).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Yes, after upgrading with:  ```ansible-galaxy collection install hetzner.hcloud --upgrade``` I succeeded in the creation a new server connected to my private network.